# How to check whether a sqlite table exist from bash file?

Tags: bash, sqlite

I get two files in the same directory:

```
foo.db
check.sh
```

in database `foo.db`, there is a table called `foo.db.1`, and in the `check.sh`, I want to check whether the table exists:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ![ -e foo.db.1 ]; then
    echo "foo.db.1 does not exist"
    exit 1
fi
```

then I got an print to say `foo.db.1 does not exist`. The script seems not working, but if I change the script to check whether the database exist instead of the table exist, it seems work:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ![ -e foo.db ]; then
    echo "foo.db does not exist"
    exit 1
fi
echo "foo.db does exist"
```

then I get the print to say 'foo.db does exist'

it seems I can check whether the database exist, but cannot check whether the table exist in the database, and I wonder how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `sqlite3` program to read an sqlite3 db

```
if sqlite3 ./foo.db <<< .schema | grep -qi 'create table foo.db.1 '; then
    echo "table foo.db.1 exists in foo.db"
fi
```

Comment: you are right, and I made some changes to make it run on bash:

Answer (score 2):

```
sqlite3 /database/path "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='<tableName>');"
```

will return either a `0` if the table does not exist or a `1` if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use double brackets or place ! outside:

```
if [[ ! -e foo.db.1 ]]; then
    echo "foo.db.1 does not exist"
    exit 1
fi

if ! [ -e foo.db.1 ]; then
    echo "foo.db.1 does not exist"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I tried both, seems still cannot find the table, I wonder whether it is because syntax of bash, maybe because it is a table in foo.db, but with bash file you can only check whether a file exist under the same directory, like the foo.db, but you cannot check whether a table(foo.db.1) exist in foo.db?

Comment: I actually thought you were checking a file. You have to use other tools to check if a file or a data object exists internally in another like `foo.db.1` inside `foo.db`.

Comment: any idea about what tool will be suitable for my situation? thanks

Comment: That's just a little odd since `foo.db.1` can't actually be a valid table inside `foo.db` can it?